# Display All Apps By One Developer / Company

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I want to open iTunes with list of all the apps by a particular developer or company and in this very case my own applicaitons.

The problem is I don't know how should the URL string be

`itms://itunes.com/apps/xxxx`

what should I replace this xxx with ? and where would I find this text. Is it the company name? If so, should I look for it in developer account's profile info.

What else could be used? I heard there is some artistId or something like that. If so, how do I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you know the developer or company that you're looking for beforehand, you can use Apple's [iTunes Link Maker web utility](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/) to generate links for the appstore (or any store really). You just put the developer's / company name in 'Search' field and set 'Media Type' to iOS Apps (or whatever  you need). After the search is completed click on the appropriate result link under 'Artists' and you'll be presented with a sheet containing a link like this:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/vasileios-akoinoglou/id339374807?uo=4

Note that you can safely replace `http://` with `itms://` so to avoid a redirection (if you use http then the link is first opened in Safari and then in Appstore).
As I can see from the link the components after `artist` is the developer / company name (whitespaces are replaced by dashes) and the `id` I think <strike>is the enrollment id</strike> (edit: it's not). I hope that this will be useful to you.

Comment: the problem is that it is the first product of the company, hence there are no search result for my company thus I cannot determine the ArtistId

Comment: @tGilani I'm still reading the [relevant docs here](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) but I'm afraid that the `artistId` is created by iTunes upon your first successfully submitted product to the store.

Answer (score 2):

The iTunes lookup API will also help in this case - simply replace the adamID for any app in the following URL:

```
    http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=524731580
```

In the results, look for the artistViewUrl to determine the best URL to link to all apps developed by this Seller

Answer (score 0):

Your URL should be in this format for the AppStore app to open it on iOS:

http://ax.search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?media=software&term=ideal%20development%20aps

This basically performs a search on a term in the appstore. it is the only bulletproof solution we have found, but it might be problematic if your developer name accidentally matches another developer or product. Also note that sometimes the search fails, in which case the AppStore app needs to be closed completely.